# delete azure table storage row without checking for existence

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I've been using azure table storage for years, and I'm not sure what the "proper" way to do this is with the newest WindowsAzure.Storage library, version 5.0.1-preview (for use in a new ASP.NET 5 application):

**Problem:**
Given a partition key and row key, delete the row without checking for existence first, and without failing if it does not exist.

**Current Solution:** This code works... but the exception handling is confusing:

```
public async Task DeleteRowAsync(CloudTable table, string partition, string row)
{
    var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(partition, row);
    entity.ETag = "*";

    var op = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
    try
    {
        await table.ExecuteAsync(op);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var result = RequestResult.TranslateFromExceptionMessage(ex.Message);
        if (result == null || result.HttpStatusCode != 404)
            throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. The exception itself pointed me to this TranslateFromExceptionMessage method... I can't find a whole lot of information on that and WrappedStorageException (the type of the exception that is thrown). Is this some kind of new/preferred way to check for 404 errors on storage exceptions? Does anyone know if all storage exceptions will now use this, or do I need to write code to test and figure it out?
2. There is an InnerException of type StorageException. Presumably our older code that used StorageException.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode could access this inner exception in the same way. Is that "OK", or is parsing these new XML error messages better or more robust somehow?
3. Is there a different approach altogether that I should be considering for this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest client ([Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables)), the delete method automatically swallows 404 responses and does not throw. This approach avoids the need to write code that introduces race conditions (checking first before performing an operations) or having to handle this condition with a try/catch block.

If you want to know if the operation actually deleted a table or it didn't exist, you can inspect the Status property of the response.

```
Response response = await tableClient.DeleteAsync();
if (response.Status == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    // entity didn't exist)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find the version which handles this scenario.
I plan to upgrade to an internal infra of my team which uses 12.6.1. Is this change included there?

Answer (score 1):

The `RequestResult.TranslateFromExceptionMessage` method is now marked `[Obsolete]` and I wanted a way to ignore 404's myself.

Based on your tip to check out the `RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode` I came up with the following:

```
try
{
    await table.ExecuteAsync(op);
}
catch (StorageException storEx)
{
    if (storEx.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode != 404)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar approach found in the AspNet WebHooks project when configured to use Azure Table Storage. Take a look at the `Microsoft.Aspnet.WebHooks.custom.AzureStorage` [StorageManager](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.AzureStorage/Storage/StorageManager.cs) class.

I'm not sure this adds much on top of what you'd already found, but they handle everything without throwing an exception and always return a status code so you can react to that as necessary.

One difference here is they pass in the `table` and the `operation` to a multi-purpose ExecuteAsync method, rather than having one specifically for delete, but that's just an implementation detail.

Relevant code from their example:

```
public async Task<TableResult> ExecuteAsync(CloudTable table, TableOperation operation)
{
    if (table == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));
    }
    if (operation == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(operation));
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(operation);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var errorMessage = GetStorageErrorMessage(ex);
        var statusCode = GetStorageStatusCode(ex);
        var message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, AzureStorageResources.StorageManager_OperationFailed, statusCode, errorMessage);
        _logger.Error(message, ex);

        return new TableResult { HttpStatusCode = statusCode };
    }
}

public string GetStorageErrorMessage(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is StorageException storageException && storageException.RequestInformation != null)
    {
        var status = storageException.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage != null ?
            storageException.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage + " " :
            string.Empty;
        var errorCode = storageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation != null ?
            "(" + storageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage + ")" :
            string.Empty;
        return status + errorCode;
    }
    else if (ex != null)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

public int GetStorageStatusCode(Exception ex)
{
    return ex is StorageException se && se.RequestInformation != null ? se.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode : 500;
}
```